# As3 - Child heredit event listener. How to stop?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, event-listener

I'm an as3 newbie. I'm experiencing this strange problem. I've created a button (type: MyButton) with two child, a text (TextField) and a image icon (type: MyIcon).
Then I've append an eventlistener mouse_click on my button.

As soon as I click on the text, the e.target on the handeler function is recognized of MyButton type. Otherwise, if I click on the image icon (child of button) the e.target is MyIcon type, instead of MyButton.

How can I prevent this? I need all click to be recorded on the button, where I've stored some attributes I need on handeler function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `e.currentTarget` instead. It returns the object that the `MouseEvent` has currently bubbled to. `e.target` returns the object that the `MouseEvent` actually started on.

Read about Event bubbling [here](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/eventbubbles-eventcancelable-and-eventcurrenttarget). It's a very important concept to grasp.

Comment: You can also set the `mouseChildren` property of the button to `false`. This will ensure the target is always the button itself, but it disable rollover and button effect on any of the buttons sub children. using the e.currentTarget is probably the best best.